# Xamarin.UITest: how to set date on DatePicker component?

Tags: android, xamarin, testing, xamarin.forms, emulation

I want to write some functional tests on my app. I have simple window with on DatePicker component:

```
<DatePicker AutomationId="PlanWyborDaty" Date="{Binding Data, Mode=TwoWay}" Format="dddd, dd-MM-yyyy" Margin="8, 0" DateSelected="OnDateChange"  />
```

I tried these codes in my test method:

```
app.Query(x => x.Marked("PlanWyborDaty").Invoke("updateDate", 2020, 9, 2));
app.Query(x => x.Class("DatePicker").Invoke("updateDate", 2020, 9, 2));
```

but date in picker is still the same. I searched a lot, and found only these methods. Any ideas?

Emulator is Pixel 2 API 28 Android 9.0

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, add DatePicker control with AutomationId="datepicker"

```
   <DatePicker AutomationId="datepicker" />
```

Then using following code in UItest.cs:

```
 [Test]
    public void DatePickerTest()
    {
        app.Tap(c => c.Marked("datepicker"));
        SetDatePicker(new DateTime(2018, 1, 1));
      
    }

public void SetDatePicker(DateTime date)
{
// needed to tap & thus select the items
string month = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(date.Month);
string day = date.Day.ToString();
string year = date.Year.ToString();

if (platform == Platform.iOS)
{
    //Invoke the native method selectRow() 
    app.Query(x => x.Class("UIPickerView").Invoke("selectRow", date.Month, "inComponent", 0, "animated", true)); // brings month in scope
    app.Tap(month); // actually selects month

    app.Query(x => x.Class("UIPickerView").Invoke("selectRow", date.Day, "inComponent", 1, "animated", true));
    app.Tap(day);

    app.Query(x => x.Class("UIPickerView").Invoke("selectRow", date.Year, "inComponent", 2, "animated", true));
    app.Tap(year);
} else // Android
{
    app.Query(x => x.Class("DatePicker").Invoke("updateDate", date.Year, date.Month, date.Day));
    app.Tap("OK");
}
}
```

Comment: I wrote the same solution in my answer.. it does not work

Comment: @Corleone It so strange, I use the code above and it works fine, can you try my code to test?

Comment: If someone else finds this not working, the Android updateDate method takes ints not strings as its arguments.